# Sass::SyntaxError in Pages#index : Error message Undefined variable: "$enable-grid-classes"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, setup-project

On my project, I try to get the configuration sent by my friend. Here is the following step I did for the moment : 
- open a new project rails
- copy / paste his package.json
- run npm install 
- copy the css and script folders in my project

And now I have the error Sass::SyntaxError in Pages#index
 / Undefined variable: "$enable-grid-classes". when I try to import ../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/grid"

Here is my application.scss

```
 */
 @charset "UTF-8";

 /* // 0. Configuration and helpers */
 @import "abstracts/_variables.scss"; 
 @import "abstracts/_mixins.scss";
 /* // @import "abstracts/animations"; */

 /* // 1. External */
 @import "vendors";

 /* // 2. Base stuff */
 @import "base/reboot";
 @import "base/base";
 @import "base/grid";
 @import "base/utilities";

 /* // 3. Components */
 @import "components/about";
 @import "components/accordion";
 @import "components/advantage";
 @import "components/burger";
 @import "components/button";
 @import "components/card";
 @import "components/computer";
 @import "components/creditcard";
 @import "components/detail";
 @import "components/demo";
 @import "components/feature";
 @import "components/gallery";
 @import "components/hero";
 @import "components/intro";
 @import "components/job";
 @import "components/keyfact";
 @import "components/leader";
 @import "components/link";
 @import "components/menu";
 @import "components/notice";
 @import "components/optin";
 @import "components/popover";
 @import "components/press";
 @import "components/pricing";
 @import "components/profile";
 @import "components/rotate";
 @import "components/sheet";
 @import "components/shape";
 @import "components/slider-advantages";
 @import "components/slider-customers";
 @import "components/slider-press";
 @import "components/slider-sheets";
 /* // @import "components/slider-team"; */
 @import "components/star";
 @import "components/sticky";
 @import "components/switch";
 @import "components/tab";
 @import "components/team";
 @import "components/testimony";
 @import "components/title";
 @import "components/trust";
```

and the css file where I have the error :

```
.col-d {
  display: flex;
}

@include mq {
  @include col;
}

@include mq(ml) {
  @include col(79px);
}

// @include mq(l) {
//   @include col(104px);
// }

@include mq(xl) {
  @include col(122px);
}

$grid-columns: 12;
$grid-gutter-width: $gutter;

$grid-breakpoints: (
  s: 0,
  t: $mq-t,
  m: $mq-m,
  ml: $mq-ml,
  // l: $mq-l,
  xl: $mq-xl,
);

$container-max-widths: (
  t: $container-t,
  m: $container-m,
  ml: $container-ml,
  // l: $container-l,
  xl: $container-xl,
);

@import "../../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/grid";
@import "../../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/utilities/flex";
```

My gemfile :

```
ruby '2.6.3'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 6.0.0'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.4'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5'
# Transpile app-like JavaScript. Read more: https://github.com/rails/webpacker
gem 'webpacker', '~> 4.0'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.7'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use Active Model has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Active Storage variant
# gem 'image_processing', '~> 1.2'

#Contentful 
gem 'contentful', '~> 2.14'
#contentful rails 
gem 'contentful_rails', '~> 0.5.0'

gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3', '>= 3.3.6'

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.4.2', require: false

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  # Easy installation and use of web drivers to run system tests with browsers
  gem 'webdrivers'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

My node_modules project is in grey tint, is it normal ? 
How can i fix this error ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried changing the loading order of the Bootstrap files? E.g.

```
// required bootstrap files
@import "../../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "../../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "../../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/scss/mixins";

// optional bootstrap files
@import "../../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/scss/grid";
...
```

Namespaces based on my own config (using Composer).